# Monodroid and Mono.Data.Sqlite.Orm.Linq transactions

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.android

I'm using the lib by Matthew Leibowitz. I have been checking it and it seems it doesn't support transactions. I can only see a BeginTransaction method but thenre's no EndTransaction/Commit counterpart. Has anybody been able to use transactions with this lib?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BeginTransaction` returns a transaction object, on which you can call `Commit`.

Comment: Did not notice that. THanks for this.